# Are there any restrictions to the C standard allowing functions to be implemented as macros?

Tags: c, macros, standards

Often, in addition to providing a function declaration, C standard headers may provide a "masking macro" to make things speedier.  For example, if I include `ctype.h`, the header file will declare

```
int isdigit(int c);
```

But it may also mask the declaration with a macro.  I believe this is a portable `isdigit` macro according to the C standard:

```
#define isdigit(c) ((c) >= '0' && (c) <= '9')
```

Of course, this macro is also dangerous because it introduces undefined behavior if you do this while the macro is defined:

```
int c = 'A';
printf("%d\n", isdigit(c++));
```

To avoid UB in this hypothetical case, I have to surround the function name with parens:  `(isdigit)(c++)`.  So, my question is:  are there any restrictions to what sort of masking macros a standard header can define?  Are they guaranteed to not cause undefined behavior if an argument expression has side effects, or are they technically allowed to have weird behavior such as we see above?  Where are the limits?

Comment: You proposed macro is not conformant. With the exceptions of the (optional) macro implementations of the `getc()` and `putc()` functions, a macro definition of a standard function may not evaluate any of its arguments more than once. If invoked as `isdigit(c++)` your macro misbehaves, but the statement works correctly with compliant macros and with a function.

Comment: Sorry, what do you mean by "standard macros"?  In any case, when I said "portable", I meant "well-behaved on all standard-compliant C compilers", when passed an appropriate argument without side effects.

Comment: The C standard states that any standard function may also be implemented as a macro.  But it also demands that any macro implementation of any standard C function (except `getc()` and `putc()`) must only evaluate its arguments once, because the macro must behave exactly as if it was a function.  Further, every function must be both declared and implemented as a function so that its address can be taken and passed around as a pointer to function.  That's pretty much the information that Paul Griffiths quoted at you from the standard.  Note that `setjmp()` is explicitly a macro.

Comment: Sorry, the wording of your original pre-edit comment confused me.

Comment: So I gathered; I apologize for misleading.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Per C11 7.1.4.1, "Use of Library Functions", particularly the last part quoted below:

> Any function declared in a header may be additionally implemented as a
>   function-like macro defined in the header, so if a library function
>   is declared explicitly when its header is included, one of the
>   techniques shown below can be used to ensure the declaration is not
>   affected by such a macro....For the same syntactic reason, it is
>   permitted to take the address of a library function even if it is also
>   defined as a macro. The use of `#undef` to remove any macro definition
>   will also ensure that an actual function is referred to. Any
>   invocation of a library function that is implemented as a macro shall
>   expand to code that evaluates each of its arguments exactly once,
>   fully protected by parentheses where necessary, so it is generally
>   safe to use arbitrary expressions as arguments.

Note that the "generally" at the end is important, there, and there are explicit exceptions. C11 7.21.7.5.2 says "the `getc` function is equivalent to `fgetc`, except that if it is implemented as a macro, it may evaluate `stream` more than once, so the argument should never be an expression with side effects", with similar language for `putc` in C11 7.21.7.7.2. In this particular case, `stream` is a `FILE *`, so under normal circumstances it would be kind of weird to have this as an expression with side-effects, but it could happen. The same is also true for their wide character counterparts, `putwc()` and `getwc()`. I am not aware of any other exceptions like this.

Comment: Interesting--I wonder if getc() and putc() requirements were actually changed in C11 (or C99 for that matter)...see my answer.

Comment: I think the "generally" is important in the last sentence. Per C11 7.21.7.5.2, "the `getc` function is equivalent to `fgetc`, except that if it is implemented as a macro, it may evaluate `stream` more than once, so the argument should never be an expression with side effects", so I think you are still correct.

Comment: The `getc()` and `putc()` exceptions were present in C89 (and C99) as well as C11.  The objective is to allow a macro implementation that normally avoids any function calls, but such macros find it difficult to avoid evaluating the file stream argument several times.  GCC provides 'expression statements' as a way to have it all; they are, however, a GCC extension, not a standard C compiler feature.

Answer (score 2):

From here: http://www.qnx.com/developers/docs/6.5.0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.qnx.doc.dinkum_en_ecpp%2Flib_over.html

> Arguments that have side effects evaluate the same way whether the expression executes the macro expansion or calls the function. Macros for the functions getc and putc are explicit exceptions to this rule.

I've found a few other references saying about the same thing (though nothing citing the C standard directly).

So it seems the limits are that only `getc()` and `putc()` may cause havoc in the way you foresee.  Apart from those two, you should be safe, assuming your platform is at least one of sane or conforming.