# What is the REALLY correct way (time) to use GetLastError()?

Tags: c++, winapi

Following an extended argument here on Stack Overflow (which has now been cleaned up by the Powers-that-Be), the question has arisen as to when one should ***really*** call the `GetLastError` function.

Note: This is ***not*** a question about style, just about:
  (a) what the standard guarantees (or not) in the case of the 'non-purist' code;
  (b) in terms of safe `winapi` programming, what is the 'best practice'.

Here's an example (adapted from the original question there posted):

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <iostream>

//#define PURIST 1

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    HANDLE hConsole = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    SMALL_RECT wSize = { 0,0,60,20 }; // Works on my screen!
    if (hConsole == nullptr) {
        cout << "Console Handle is Null" << endl;
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        char message[256];
        if (!SetConsoleWindowInfo(hConsole, TRUE, &wSize)) {
            #ifdef PURIST
            // 'Purist' code ...
            DWORD eCode = GetLastError();
            sprintf(message, "SetConsoleWindowInfo failed; code = %d!", eCode);
            #else
            // More normal code ...
            sprintf(message, "SetConsoleWindowInfo failed; code = %d!", GetLastError());
            #endif
        }
        else {
            strcpy(message, "SetConsoleWindowInfo call succeeded!");
        }
        cout << message << endl;
    }
    getchar(); // Just to stop console closing!
    return 0;
}
```

Obviously, the 'purist' approach will **always** work properly! However, does the `c++` language standard guarantee that the 'normal' approach will also work? (That is, can one be sure that `GetLastError()` as an argument to `sprintf` will be the first code to execute after testing the return value of `SetConsoleWindowInfo()` ?)

PS: Please don't judge me too harshly on the  quality of the code! As I said, it is an adaptation of the original question.

EDIT: A more typical situation (that I use a lot in my Windows apps) looks like this:

```
if (<WinApi call failed>) {
    TCHAR eText[256];
    FormatMessage(FORMAT_MESSAGE_FROM_SYSTEM, nullptr, GetLastError(), 0, eText, 255, nullptr);
    // Do something with eText, etc. ...
    return <error code>;
}
```

But again, `GetLastError()` is the only non-const argument.

Comment: That doesn't have anything to do with c++. You call `GetLastError()` immediately after detecting an error was indicated by the previous WinaAPI function.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ Looking for c++ standard, hence that tag! Did you refer to the original question (which is getting a bit ugly)? I'm just trying to make it a more appropriate discussion.

Comment: Function arguments may be evaluated in any order. Also 'Purist' code should probably look like this: `auto const last_error{::GetLastError()};`

Comment: my position - `GetLastError` not part of *c++* standard and *c++* have 0 knowledge about this api and what is thread last error at all. question here - are can be something in concrete code which change last error value between api fail and call `GetLastError()`. in concrete code - this is only pass constant string literal `"SetConsoleWindowInfo failed; code = %d!"`. so - are pass string literal can change thread os error code ? if assume that yes, why we can not assume that call function `GetLastError()` by self can not change this code ?

Comment: @VTT - *Function arguments may be evaluated in any order* - of course. but all before call functions. here only 2 argument - `GetLastError()` and string literal. so you think that pass string literal can change last thread error code ?

Comment: @VTT - Yes, but in this case, `GetLastError()` is the only non-constant argument!

Comment: function argument evaluation order is not guaranteed by C++.  So if you don't want to be a purist then you'll have to make sure that you can't call a CRT function that might be implemented with a winapi call while the argument expressions are computed.  Since most programmers haven't spent time reading the CRT source code, or thought through the consequences of expression evaluation, this tends to go wrong often.  Not here, but maybe next time.  Avoid confusing pragmatism with purism.

Comment: Yes, but `GetLastError()` should be placed somewhere where it won't be easily interleaved with some other code. So you should never use `GetLastError()` as a function argument, even if this function currently takes a single argument.

Comment: @VTT - why we can not  use `GetLastError()` as function argument, even if this function currently takes a single argument ?

Comment: Weird thing, here, is that `GetLastError()` is itself a `WinAPI` call and will itself reset the last error! Hehe.

Comment: @RbMm Because it can be easily interleaved with some other code. Even without changing function invocation. For example: First you have `void foo(DWORD error_code);` and call it like `foo(::GetLastError());`, then `foo` signature changes to something like `void foo(DWORD error_code, std::wstring path = {});` and BOOM, code gets silently broken.

Comment: @Adrian - `GetLastError` not reset or change last error code. only return it value. but if we say use `/GUARD:CF` - before call any exported api will be call to so check function. may be compiler itself implemented some CFG. are standard guarantee that this calls/checks not change last error value ?

Comment: @RbMm its the same as with RAII, you may name lots of cases where your code will not need it - but any way you should use it every where to make sure your code is safe. You simply don't waste time giving even a chance a part of code might be broken. C++ gives you lots of changes to shoot your self in the foot.

Comment: @VTT - we speak about **concrete** code, with function `printf` where **no** hidden, default arguments

Comment: @marcinj - this is question about style, or about absolute concrete code case ?

Comment: @RbMm I am not sure - I can imagine someone can do `#define sprintf  XXXXX` where XXXXX is some code that might break GetLastError value assumptions.

Comment: @VTT - of course we can write function like `void fn(int e, int f = someapicall());` and call it as `fn(GetLastError())` but here `GetLastError()` not single argument. because order or argument undefined - of course here UB. but you at begin write about **single argument** (on binary level

Comment: @marcinj - you say about **changing src code**. i say only about **concrete** code

Comment: I would always do it the purist way since it's correct now and stable under refactor.  If someone blows through the codebase with a refactor or a sed expression changing calls around, I don't want them to have to worry about reading all the code to see if they're potentially breaking a line of code with GetLastError in it.

Comment: @Adrian - i think you need clear state that - 1) this is not question about style 2) function have not hidden, default arguments. 3) all argument, except `GetLastError()` - compiler time constant 4) function - not a macro, expanded to call with more arguments. in this case question - are passing constant arguments to function - can affect last error value(not part of c++) ?

Comment: @RbMm You know the drill: *Always code as if the guy who ends up maintaining your code will be a violent psychopath who knows where you live.* Even if code works as expected right now it **must** be written in a manner that would make introduction of bugs in the future less likely. Leaving `GetLastError` invocation inside of function will make modification of other function arguments not trivial - that is you will need to politely ask that future violent psychopath to check those future arguments to be free of side effects and to move `GetLastError` invocation otside if they are not .

Comment: @Adrian - i not ask about style. good it or bad. may be you correct and this is bad style. probably if little change code - this can lead to nasty error and very hard will be found this in future. but here question about absolute concrete case - are passing compiler time constant can affect last error value

Comment: Voting to close question because the length of the comment thread suggests that the question is too broad. I think in its current state it can be interpreted both as a question about style and also as a purely technical question.

Comment: It's a purely technical question about whether both styles lead to correct behavior, however there is some ambiguity as to whether it's about how the code is written in this concrete case or as a general rule.

Comment: @zett42 - agree, because this i for clarify the question. and do not mix coding style issues with the formal correctness of a particular code

Comment: @zett42 - No! Question is about what the standard guarantees in terms of the 'non-purist' approach. Maybe vote to delete 'stylist' comments?

Comment: @Adrian *Obviously, the 'purist' approach will always work properly!* - we can say that **check** function return value - can change last error. and why call function (`GetLastError()` in this concrete case) can not change last error ? in any case will be some c++ code between fail api and call `GetLastError()`. check function return - (if ()) - already come compiler code ! then - c++ can not direct call function but do some check **before** function call (like CFG checks) - what if this checks change last error ? so even purist way **can fail** if stay on purist positions.

Comment: @marcinj: Defining a standard library name as a macro has undefined behavior anyway.

Comment: @IInspectable - Do you just like being nasty? Why spoil other folks' questions, unless you have something **constructive** to add?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I will separate this question into two independent questions:

1. *Does "normal code" example work as expected?*
   Yes, this exact code will work as expected. Other function arguments are built-in types and even though evaluation of order function arguments is not defined none of them can interfere with `GetLastError` invocation.
2. *Is "normal code" example a correct way to invoke `GetLastError`?*
   It is not, even though running this code yields expected results. And the reason for this is that **use of `GetLastError` as function argument introduces implicit constraint on other function arguments** that they must have no last-error changing side effects. This makes code more error prone and more difficult to maintain.

So the Rule of thumb would be to store last error value in some variable prior to calling other functions or creating / destroying objects.

Comment: agree with both 1 and 2. simply i initial argue only about 1 (question about formal correctness concrete code, not about style). and listen argument that even passing constant string literal "xxx" can affect thread last error code

Comment: That's as close to a definitive answer as I could expect! And worth noting that all M/S examples use your stated "Rule of Thumb!"

Comment: I would also add that your answer will probably be very useful to lots of (new) `WinAPI` programmers! I certainly have used `GetLastError()` as an argument quite frequently but, now, I see that it is not implementation-safe! Thanks!

Comment: @Adrian Actually I don't think "all" MS examples follow best practices in this case. Already the [example for `GetLastError`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/debug/retrieving-the-last-error-code) itself puts way too much stuff between the function that failed and the call to `GetLastError`. It is technically correct (like the "normal code" of this question), but easy to break when maintaining the code.

Comment: @zett42 - Yes, but in the example you link, `GetLastError()` is assigned to a (temporary) variable … **not** passed as an argument in itself. This is what I meant.

Comment: @Adrian In that example `GetLastError()` is assigned to a (temporary) variable after `ErrorExit` is called (last error is set during `GetProcessId` in `main`) so the situation is even worse. However I should mention that since C does not have overloaded functions, default parameters, constructors and destructors delaying `GetLastError` invocation in C is less error prone. Also note that `ErrorExit` is terminating function so even if we miss correct error code program will die anyway.

Answer (score 2):

The non-purist way is fine *here*

> When calling a function (whether or not the function is inline, and whether or not explicit function call syntax is used), every value computation and side effect associated with any argument expression, or with the postfix expression designating the called function, is sequenced before execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called function.

[Rule 3](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/eval_order), I think this corresponds to §8.2.2.5 in the draft version of the C++17 standard.

And in this case there aren't any other arguments with side-effects.

But note that it's fragile, and if someone does something naughty like

```
#define sprintf (log_call_to_sprintf(), sprintf)
```

you're out of luck.

Comment: of course question not about case when function have default, hidden arguments like `void fn(int e, int f = someapicall());` and call it as `fn(GetLastError())`, not case when function - really macro which expand to call function with **more** arguments. not question of style. but question - are passing constant string literal - can change thread last error value (which at all not part of c++)

Comment: Of course you could imagine anything (and a conforming implementation could [to some degree](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19298715/are-there-any-restrictions-to-the-c-standard-allowing-functions-to-be-implemente) define `sprintf` as a macro that modified `LastError`, and questions about the Win32 API can't be answered using only the C++ standard, but I can't imagine a non-pathological implementation where that was the case.

Comment: i think we need clarify and narrow down the question and state clearly - the function is not macro, which expands into something else, the function has no hidden arguments. all another arguments - compiler time constants. so can passing compiler time constants affect windows last error code (not part of c++ at all) ?

Answer (score 1):

let we have next code snippet

```
if (<WinApi call failed>) {
    SomeApiCall(arg<1>, .., GetLastError(), .., arg<n>);
}
```

and assume next conditions:

1. `SomeApiCall` not a macro expanded to something else - this is
   exactly some function call
2. all arguments to function (`arg<1>` ... `arg<n>`), except `GetLastError()`, used only
   **internal *c/c++* language expressions**, which calculated without any
   external functions calls (including language support libraries)
3. nothing exist in arguments, what can lead to hardware exception,
   like divide by zero, reference memory by pointer, etc
4. this not question about coding style

for example this call

```
SomeApiCall( "some text", GetLastError(), 8);
```

conform to 2 and 3

in this case we can say that `GetLastError()` will be called before thread's last-error code value can be changed, after `<WinApi call failed>`. because:

- thread's last-error code can be changed only as result of some
  windows api calls
- all arguments to function ( `SomeApiCall` ) calculated **before**
  execution of every expression or statement in the body of the called
  function
- so between `<WinApi call failed`> and `SomeApiCall` exist only
  `arg<1>`, .., `GetLastError()`, .., `arg<n>`
- due 2 and 3 - no any direct or indirect (in exception handler)
  windows api call, because *c/c++* **language don't know about windows
  api** and **can not by self** call it (without some external for
  language calls, including  language support libraries)
- so between `<WinApi call failed`> and `GetLastError()` call - no any
  windows api calls
- as result value of last-error code will be not changed between
  `<WinApi call failed`> and `GetLastError()` call